# What is our stance on answers recommending illegal actions?

Tags: discussion

There’s [a question about a cat that is neglected by the legal owner and cared for by the asker](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/31719/16350).

The question is whether the asker can or should take the cat with them in an upcoming move.

The legalities seem clear, [as explained in one answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/31725/16350), but there’s [a second answer that basically recommends ignoring the law](https://pets.stackexchange.com/a/32735/16350) and acting in what they claim the cat’s best interest.

If we ignore that the question possibly belongs to Law SE, what is our position on answers that knowingly recommend illegal actions?

Answer (score 1):

**We should not take a strong stance**

I am writing this answer with only one thing in my mind: [illegal drugs are used pretty routinely to treat Feline Infectious Peritonitis, a.k.a FIP or FCoV.](https://www.theatlantic.com/science/archive/2020/05/remdesivir-cats/611341/) Apparently this has been going on for years, but once Remdesivir is used in some capacity to treat Covid patients, it received more public attention. Although illegally produced and obtained medication is used, the treatment is highly effective and to the best of my knowledge no one got into trouble.

Using this information, and recalling that

- There are differences between countries about legality of some actions;
- Illegal actions are enforced differently (or not enforced at all), depending on regions;

putting a strong emphasis on legality might be hurtful and should be considered in a case-by-case basis. However, a good answer should always disclose legality of the suggested actions.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, there's a difference between questions about illegal actions and answers promoting illegal actions.

### Questions

I think questions asking "Should I do x (even though x is illegal)?" should be closed as oppinion based.

A well-written question should ask "Is action x illegal?" instead of "Should I do action x?". Granted, this kind of question is probably off topic here and it may depend on the location of OP. What is illegal in one place might be perfectly fine elsewhere.

### Answers

Let's assume someone posted a question that is clearly on-topic and someone else posted an answer promoting an ilegal action. I see no difference to someone posting bad advice or a factual wrong answer, so downvoting it seems like the right course of action. Since some actions are illegal only in some countries, leaving a comment for the author is a courtesy we shouldn't forget.

However, if someone promotes violence, like killing or injuring animals or people, the post violates the Code of Conduct and should be flagged for the mods.